# Function not pulling image or text from custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions, custom-field

```
//Custom Post Type
register_post_type('inf_main_feature', array(
      'labels' => array(
            'name'   => 'Main Featured',
            'singular_name' => 'Main Featured',
            'add_new' => __( 'Add New' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Feature' ),
            'view_item' => 'View Feature',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Story',
            'new_item' => __('New Featire'),
            'view_item' => __('View New Feature'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Features'),
            'not_found' =>  __('No entries found'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No entries found in Trash'),
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    '_edit_link' =>  'post.php?post=%d',
    'rewrite' => array(
            "slug" => "homebox",
            "with_front" => false,
    ),
    'query_var' => true,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'page-attributes', 'thumbnail'),
));

 //Custom Fields

 Carbon_Container::factory('custom_fields', __('Feature Options', 'inf'))
     ->show_on_post_type('inf_main_feature')
->add_fields(array(
              Carbon_Field::factory('text', 'feature_url', 'The Link'),
            Carbon_Field::factory('attachment', 'main_image', 'Main Image')
                    ->help_text('Image Dimensions - 600 × 600 pixels.')
    ));

// Main Feature
function inf_feature() {
  $args = array (
'post_type' => 'inf_main_feature',
 'posts_per_page' => 1
);
  $feature = get_post($args)[0]->ID;
 $feature_link = get_post_meta($feature->ID, 'feature_url', true);
 $main_boxID =  get_post_meta($feature->ID, 'main_image', full);
  $main_image = get_post($main_boxID[0])->guid;
 ?>
```

## My HTML

```
  div class="main_feature_container"
      div class="main_feature"
      a href="php echo $feature_link"
        img src="php echo $main_image"
      /a
  /div
```

#### forget the tags <> and < ? etc... I am a noob with this editor and cant get it to render properly.

i cannot get this to pull the image or the link from this custom post type.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way, may help you. I just fetch from a specific post 's image from a specific Post Type called "gameshowwarriorsw".

```
        $gameShowWarriorsWorld = new WP_Query( 'post_type=gameshowwarriorsw&orderby=date&order=DESC&p=371' );   
        while ($gameShowWarriorsWorld->have_posts()) : $gameShowWarriorsWorld->the_post();


        $postTitle = get_the_title();
        $postid = get_the_id();
        $postContent    = get_the_content();



    ?>

        <li>    <a href="#" onclick="return get_inzenwarriorhero(<?php echo $postid ; ?>);">
                     <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(219,143)); ?>
                </a> 
        </li>
    <?php 
        endwhile;
       wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```